# How to return pandas dataframe in pyspark UDF

Tags: pyspark, user-defined-functions

I need to process a dataset in user-defined-function, the process should return a pandas dataframe which should be converted into a pyspark structure using the declared schema

```
def predict_data(id, data, scope):
    data = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data, columns=columnNames)
    data = process((id, data, scope))
    return data # print statements shows correct output
udf_predict = F.udf(result_data, schema)
df = df.withColumn("result", udf_predict(df.ID, df.data, F.lit(SCOPE)))
```

the result always comes empty eventhough I know the returned `data` varialbe have the correct output.
what should be done to catch the output correctly ?

Comment: Your question is a bit ambiguous, but based on what I understand, you could look into using a `pandas_udf` instead of a traditional spark UDF: https://databricks.com/blog/2017/10/30/introducing-vectorized-udfs-for-pyspark.html. This allows you to harness the vectorized operations in pandas. You only need to define the output schema and treat the input data frame in the `pandas_udf` as a Pandas data frame.